# laravel jquery run custom autocomplet onclick

Tags: jquery, laravel, search, autocomplete, onclick

I have a custom.catcoplete that runs if the input minLength is 3. When i click outside of the input the autocomplete disapears.

Now you have to add a letter for the autocomplete to reappear, but i want the autocomplete to reappear if you click on the input again.

I don't know where to add this event listener.

quicksearch.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
            var that = this,
                currentCategory = "";
            $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                if (item.category_caption !== currentCategory) {
                    ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category_caption + "</li>");
                    currentCategory = item.category_caption;
                }
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            });
        }
    });

    $('#quicksearch').catcomplete({
        source: '/search/quick',
        minLength: 3,
        classes: {
            "ui-autocomplete": "quicksearch"
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.category === "search_further") {
                window.location = ui.item.source;
                return false;
            }

            $('#quicksearch').blur();

            openViewModal({
                type: ui.item.category,
                id: ui.item.id,
                url: ui.item.source || '',
            });
        }
    }).on("focus", function () {
        $(this).catcomplete("search", '');
    });
});
```

Can somebody help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **onfocus** handler I changed from:

```
$(this).catcomplete("search", '');
```

to:

```
if (this.value.length > 2) {       // if there are enough chars
        $(this).trigger('input');  // mimic an input event
}
```

Furthemore, I added a check on **category_caption**: when undefined do nothing.

```js
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript1",
    "ActionScript2",
    "ActionScript3",
    "ActionScript4",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var that = this,
                currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (item.category_caption = undefined && item.category_caption !== currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category_caption + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category_caption;
            }
            that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }
});

$('#quicksearch').catcomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 3,
    classes: {
        "ui-autocomplete": "quicksearch"
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item.category === "search_further") {
            window.location = ui.item.source;
            return false;
        }

        $('#quicksearch').blur();


    }
}).on("focus", function () {
    if (this.value.length > 2) {
       $(this).trigger('input');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Type...act...</p>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="quicksearch">Tags: </label>
    <input id="quicksearch">
</div>
```

Comment: O yeah this works! i was trying .bind('click focus') before, but that didn't work.  Thank you very much!